# nested syncronized block on one object

Tags: java, multithreading, locking, mutex, deadlock

Is it possible that the current instance of a Thread be able to lock itself and causes a deadlock? For example, in this part of code, I believe the current instance of thread can't enter to second synchronization block because it already has a lock on s1 and it can't lock it again. but the code doesn't work that way. and prints the message in the second synchronized block. can someone please explain to me what I am missing? Thank You.

```
public class DeadLock {

    final String s1="s1";


    Thread t1=new Thread("t1"){

        @Override
        public void run() {
            synchronized (s1) {
                synchronized (s1) {
                    System.out.println(" t1 thread..");

                }
            }
        }
    };



    public static void main(String[] args) {

        DeadLock deadLock=new DeadLock();
        deadLock.t1.start();



    }

}
```

Comment: The same thread can lock the same lock as often as it wants. Why do you think there should be an artificial limit to that just once?

Answer (score 3):

Java monitors are reentrant. Nested locking such as you demonstrated in your code works just fine. This is what happens when you can call synchronized methods of the same object from other synchronized methods.